# SPI SS line gets raised to ~3.7V on custom PCB

Tags: pcb, spi, esp32

On a custom PCB design I did recently, I ran into an issue.

The basic concept of the PCB is connecting up to ten NFC sensors (via SPI) through USB-C connections (not using actual USB communication, but simply routing the wiring through USB-C wires).

All SPI lines (MOSI, MISO, SCK) go to an ESP32 mounted on the PCB.

The SS lines for each sensor are connected to an MCP23016 I/O expander (SENS_EXP on the PCB).

On a breadboard prototype, the whole thing works and sensors get recognized via SPI. However, on the PCB, sensors do not get recognized.

I have managed to (most likely) locate the issue: During sensor initialization, instead of staying at 0V, the SS line for each sensor briefly rises to ~3.7V instead of staying at 5V. This most likely causes the sensor to become inactive and thus not be recognized. I assume it occurs at the moment an SPI transaction is initiated, however I'm not 100% sure of that.

From the PCB layout posted below, could you identify any possible cause for this? The problem occurs for all sensors (meaning pins GP0.0 to GP1.1 on the MCP23016). On the breadboard prototype, using the same IO expander and same ESP32, the SS lines behave as expected.

The problem also occurs without any wiring (or sensors) connected to the PCB, so it must be related to something on the PCB itself. We have tested three identical copies of the PCB and the problem exists for all of them. Also, there are no measurable shorts between any of the related pins.

Thank you in advance!

[image: The PCB]

Comment: Show circuit diagram. Most probably there's an error in the circuit diagram or PCB wiring. Examine your EDA errors and warnings section.

Comment: This was designed as a PCB directly, as I already had it working as a breadboard prototype, wired exactly the same. I understand this is not ideal however.
My EDA gives no errors or warnings, and I have measured all pins with a multimeter and found no shorts.

Comment: To add: I'm assuming it's specifically related to the PCB itself (e.g. some of the SPI traces being too close together?), as the exact same wiring on a breadboard works.

Comment: Show 5 pictures: circuit diagram, photo of board and photo of breadboard (two latter from both sides). Otherwise it would be next to impossible to help you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/T1yp4LO Here's the breadboard prototype (which probably won't help as it's quite messy, but works) and the PCB.
I'm working on the circuit diagram at the moment.

Comment: @Davwys - Hi, From the question: "*During sensor initialization [...] the SS line for each sensor briefly rises to ~3.7V*"; however, from a later [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/484253/spi-ss-line-gets-raised-to-3-7v-on-custom-pcb#comment1231128_484259): "*I sadly don't have an oscilloscope*". Without a scope, you *don't know* what DC level the SS signal has. The ~3.7V on your DMM might be oscillations between 0V and 5V, and so not a fixed, valid logic high, as also mentioned in comments. You need to get a scope (better) or logic analyser for improved troubleshooting.

Comment: Please explain first which device uses which voltage levels? I see I2C lines pulled up to 5V, and the IO expanders using 5V supply. I hope the ESP32 has 5V tolerant IO then. Which NFC chip it would be and what IO voltages does the SPI bus use? I hope you have not connected a 5V IO expander to drive 5V out to a NFC chip SS pin that must be driven with 3.3V. It would explain why the SS pin gets 3.7V; it means IO expander tries to drive 5V into  SS input, but the SS input has internal protection diodes to 3.3V, which limits voltage to 3.3+0.4 = 3.7V . Excess current will flow into IO pin then.

Comment: I will try to get access to an oscilloscope or logic analyser and report back with my findings.
@Justme Yes, the ESP32 IO works on 5V just fine, same with my full breadboard prototype. The problem occurs even without any NFC sensors connected (so just the bare PCB with nothing but the ESP32) - so that can't really be it.
Interestingly enough, I am using PN532 NFC sensors that have built-in logic level converters for handling 5V - BUT those don't apply to SPI mode, apparently. This seems really strange to me, since they have always worked with 5V logic during my testing.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to tell a lot without the schematic that you used to drive the net list into the layout package. You did use a schematic to derive the net list did you not??

Things that are obvious problems.

1. Distributing the 5V rail around the board on an 8 mil trace is not good. Your prototype has a lot more copper than this and a bus bar in the plug board.
2. No bulk filter capacitors on the 5V to GND busses.
3. No bypass capacitors for the two port expander chips.
4. Ground plane stitches using 8 mil traces.

You should be doing some debug of this with an oscilloscope. Try to see if you have serious sagging of the 5V bus due to the overly small trace size used without any capacitance to hold it up.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!
I did not use a schematic file for the net list - is that such a bad idea?

About the other points:

1. Thank you, I'll change this for the next version

2. Thanks, will be added - what capacitance would you recommend?

3. Thanks, will be added - what capacitance would you recommend?

4. This was an oversight on some of the stitches, I'll also change them to a larger size.

Comment: I sadly don't have an oscilloscope, but measured an output voltage sag of 0.1V at the sensor farthest from the VIN (connected with a 50cm USB cable). I assume this should be acceptable? (it was powered via USB, which gave 4.75V input and has worked for powering breadboard prototypes with up to four sensors in the past)

Comment: @Davwys - It is typical to use bypass capacitors for chips like your expanders with a value of 0.1uF. Bulk capacitance to enhance filtering of the 5V to GND rails would use 10uf or 22uF. Make sure that the bypass capacitors for chips connect as directly and as short as possible between the VDD and VSS pins of the chips.

Comment: @Davwys - Not using a schematic creates several problems. Here are a few. (1) You lose a review step to ensure that you have the connectivity you intend.  (2) The schematic is the electrical engineering communications tool. Not some photo of a plug board. (3) The netlist from the schematic drives into the layout tool to ensure connectivity is maintained. It gives the layout tool design checker something to check against. It also gives the layout tool decent names for the nets (as long as you label them all on your schematic).

Comment: That does sound bad - I will try and work with a schematic for the next revision then. It seems though that since the board is quite "crowded", the schematic for it would be quite chaotic - any good advice for working on that?
Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond to my many trivial questions, as you might have guessed I don't have any electrical engineering background (just some hobbyist experience) :)

Comment: In most (all?) EDA packages, nets on the same schematic sheet with the same label are considered connected, even if there's no physical line between them. You should be able to spread your parts out as much as necessary. Most support multiple sheets as well, but different packages use different mechanisms to make connections between sheets.

Answer (score 2):

There're limited number of possibilities when your problem can occur:

- you have the differences between the prototype and the PCB:

  - circuit is drawn wrongly in your EDA tool;
  - wrong connections are being made on the circuit or board levels.
- there's a shortage or no contact somewhere on the board.
- something is defective on the board.

As soon as your EDA tool does not state any errors then most probably it is human error drawing circuit diagram improperly, and not the board layout problem.

Next, not sure how to treat your statement "instead of staying at 0V, the SS line for each sensor briefly rises to ~3.7V instead of staying at 5V". SS is select line for the SPI device, and when device is not selected it must be logical 1 (3.7V is **ok** for logical 1 for TTL level). You must not set more than one SPI device with SS low because there may be communication/electrical conflict between them.

In general layout is not that good as Michael said, but I guess it must not cause showing 3.7V when it must be 0V. You have logical 1 instead of logical 0 you expect, and you either have wrong expectation of logical 0, measure it in wrong time, or have hardware problem (or maybe MCU software problem).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

The connections on the MCP23016 seem fine; if I test-toggle them directly, they always go to the correct 5V or 0V. Only when SPI is running does it go to 3.7V.

I'm aware the 3.7V is ok for logical 1, but at that point during initialization it should be logical 0 - hence why I'm assuming the problem stems from there. But can't a short be surely impossible if the pin is controllable at any time when SPI communication is not running?